# Getting random word of same length using python library

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I want to get same legnth random word for given word for any language.

eg - love:nice, fine:hate(radomly generated word with same length)

I am using https://pypi.org/project/wordfreq/, because it offers support to many languages.

code:

```
query = req_data.get("query", None)
in_language = req_data.get("in_language", "auto")
out_language = req_data.get("out_language", "en")
res = []
for word in query.split(" "):
    trans = translate(word, out_language, in_language)
    res.append([word, [trans,random_words(lang=out_language, wordlist='best', nwords=1, bits_per_word=len(word)+1) ]])
return jsonify(res)
```

My logic

```
[word, [trans,random_words(lang=out_language, wordlist='best', nwords=1, bits_per_word=len(word)+1) ]]
```

where
word = input word
out_langauge = langauge of output word
trans = translation of word in output  language

But still for input words I am getting random word with different length. Also same word appear twice. Ideally there should be different random word for each source word, with the same length

result -

```
[['I', ['yo', 'de']], ['like', ['me gusta', 'a']], ['good', ['bueno', 'el']], ['', ['', 'de']], ['in', ['en', 'el']]]
```

Comment: @usr2564301: thanks for your comment, I have added the code snippet

Comment: Can you please clarify the error by providing an expected (minimal) result vs. the actual result? To me it is unclear why you are complaining about different word lengths when you are *translating* words of the same length...